# Get a User's OAuth Connected Applications via API

Tags: api, oauth

Is there a way to get the list of oauth connected applications of a given user (of a set of users) via SOAP/REST API?
Thanks,
Uri

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SOQL to get full list of connected apps.

```
SELECT Id, name FROM ConnectedApplication
```

Find [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_connectedapplication.htm) for more